# Definitions of Serial TTL UART MCU acronyms

Tags: microcontroller, uart, serial, ttl

I was looking for a comprehensive list of terms and acronyms concerning serial peripheral communication including their descriptions and, crucially, how they relate to each other. Since this site often comes up in searches for individual terms I thought it might be useful to collect all these terms in one place.

You may contribute to the Community Wiki answer below.

This has been collecting some downvotes. Please comment on whether you'd like to see this information deleted or why it is unhelpful.

Comment: @thebusybee I did; the answer below is my own. I made it a Community Wiki, so you are free to offer constructive contributions. Not sure what to make of all the downvotes.

Comment: That's a good idea. To make this preparation visible, you could add a note to your question.

Answer (score 0):

> `serial` -
> The sending of data in sequential bits

> `peripheral` -
> A device connected to a computer system but not part of its core components

> `bitbang` -
> A method of implementing peripheral communication through software as opposed to dedicated hardware for generating and processing data signals

> `DB-9` -
> Also `DE-9`, it is a 9-pin version of the early DB-25 style of physical connector consisting of 9 pins arranged in 2 rows commonly used for interfacing peripherals over the RS-232 serial data communication interface

> `COM` -
> *`Communication port`* The name of an addressable serial port interface originated by IBM using the `DB-9` connector

> `RS-232` -
> *`Recommended Standard #232`* Also known as EIA/TIA-232, this is an interface standard for serial data communication

> `RS-485` -
> *`Recommended Standard #485`* Also known as EIA/TIA-485(-A) is an interface standard for balanced-pair serial data communication

> `FTDI` -
> *`Future Technology Devices International Limited`* This is a Scottish semiconductor company which produces a very popular USB-to-Serial adapter IC (integrated circuit)

> `FT232RL` -
> The part number of an IC produced by FTDI commonly found in TTL Serial adapters

> `TTL` -
> *`Transistor-Transistor Logic`* Denotes signal voltages at the transistor logic-level of 3v to 5v

> `MCU` -
> *`Microcontroller unit`* Also MC, UC, or μC, it is a single IC chip with complex, computer-like functionality

> `UART` -
> *`Universal Asynchronous Receiver/Transmitter`* Is a simple protocol for exchanging serial data utilizing between 2 to 9 data signals

> `USB` -
> *`Universal Serial Bus`* A modern serial data communication standard that is extendable, auto-configurable, and highly complex

> `RX` -
> *`Receive`* Is the signal pin used for receiving serial data at an implied TTL voltage

> `TX` -
> *`Transmit`* Is the signal pin used for sending serial data at an implied TTL voltage

> `RXD` -
> *`Receive Data`* Is a signal pin (#2 on DB9) used for incoming serial data per the RS232 standard

> `TXD` -
> *`Transmit Data`* Is a signal pin (#3 on DB9) used for outgoing serial data per the RS232 standard

> `DTR` -
> *`Data Terminal Ready`* Is a signal pin (#4 on DB9) used for an optional flow control mechanism of the RS232 standard

> `GND` -
> *`Ground`* Is a voltage reference pin (#5 on DB9) used for signal ground

> `DSR` -
> *`Data Set Ready`* Is a signal pin (#6 on DB9) used for an optional flow control mechanism of the RS232 standard

> `RTS` -
> *`Request to Send`* Is a signal pin (#7 on DB9) used for an optional flow control mechanism of the RS232 standard

> `CTS` -
> *`Clear to Send`* Is a signal pin (#8 on DB9) used for an optional flow control mechanism of the RS232 standard

> `TXL` -
> *`Transmit LED`* Is a status pin capable of driving an LED to indicate transmit activity on the COM port

> `RXL` -
> *`Receive LED`* Is a status pin capable of driving an LED to indicate receive activity on the COM port

> `VCC` -
> *`Voltage Common Collector`* Is a power-carrying connection with a higher voltage relative to GND

> `VSS` -
> *`Voltage Source Supply`* Same as GND

> `SPI` -
> *`Serial Peripheral Interface` is a synchronous serial communication interface well suited for short distances

> `I2C` -
> *`Inter-Integrated Circuit`* Also IIC or I<sup>2</sup>C, it is a serial communications bus well suited for short distance peripheral-microcontroller communication

> `TWI` -
> *`Two-Wire Interface`* Alternative name for I2C

> `VCP` -
> *`Virtual COM Port`* A component of modern USB-to-Serial adapter drivers that allows the operating system to present a legacy COM port to applications that expect or require it for serial communication

Comment: The so-called "DB-9" connector should really be called "DE-9", according to Cannon, who introduced the D-subminature connector family.  The second letter (A - E) indicates the shell size.

Comment: @PeterBennett I've never seen it referred to by those letters, except on wikipedia, but I suppose that in and of itself enough reason to make a mention of it. Thanks

Comment: The normal density D-subminature connectors are DA-15, DB-25, DC-37, DD-50 and DE-9. (looks like the 9 pin was an afterthought :-) )